# You don't have permisission necessary to save the file,PHP Apache

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I just installed LAMP server, which works fine.  But when I code a PHP script and try to save it in `/var/www/html`, it says:

```
You don't have permisission necessary to save the file
```

Help me!  How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You don't have permission to save a file in a directory that belongs to Apache, it is that simple. The easiest thing would be to create a directory, let's say "webstuff", in your home directory, then move everything from /var/www/html to it, and create (as root) a symbolic link from /var/www/html to the webstuff directory.

Answer (score 4):

## Three quick steps

**Add your user to the www-data group**

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

**Change the owner of `/var/www`**

```
sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www
```

**Change the permissions recursively on `/var/www`**

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /var/www
```

NB:  Replace *username* in the commands with your username.

Comment: If the user already exists (which I think is correct in this case) you want to use usermod -a -G www-data username

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @ReubenSwartz.  You're right.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: This will work but I would argue that editing files directly on /var/www/html/ is asking for problems. I would use a directory in /home/ to edit the pages. And have a cron job create a backup and copy the edits over when put into a "synch" directory in the same /home.

Comment: Sure, that's valid, @Rinzwind, and I agree.  My attempt was just to make a simple solution that was fine for the average user.  Until recently, I always edited my files straight in `/var/www` (and no I didn't switch because I had issues.  :) )

Comment: `chmod -R 755`? What's the need to make all those files executable?

Comment: Hmm, good point again.  I do it that way since I fairly frequently have scripts inside `/var/www`, but it's true that a 644 would be sufficient for the average user.

Comment: Thank you guys! I fixed this problem.But,End up with another one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/790473/php-scripts-doesnt-executed